# Angular AuthGuard and login persistence: Router automatically redirects to non-truthy route even if logged in

Tags: angular, authentication, persistence, angular-router-guards

As the title suggests, I want to protect routes via `canLoad`. This works to some extent. However, I have two issues with the code.

Here are my code snippets

**AppComponent**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authServ.reauthenticate().subscribe()
}
```

**AuthService**

```
user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null as any);
reauthenticate(): Observable<User> {
    // return HTTP call here and pipe the user data into user BehaviorSubject
}
```

**AuthGuard**

```
canLoad(){
      return this.authServ.user.pipe(
        map((user) => {
          if (!!user?._token) {
            return true;
          }
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        })
      );
}
```

As you can guess, the router can access the user but still redirects to the /login path. Knowing it doesn't work, I brute-forced my way, making two HTTP calls to the server (which is generally bad, I know) to trick the system into acknowledging a persistent user. Here is the code snippet.

**AuthGuard**

```
canLoad() {
      return this.authServ.user.pipe(
        switchMap((user) => {
          if (!!user && !!user._token) {
            return of(user);
          }
          return this.authServ.reauthenticate();
        }),
        map((user) => {
          if (!!user?._token) {
            return true;
          }
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        })
      );
}
```

So my question boils down to either of these two things:

1. How can I make sure that I only call the re-tokenizer endpoint only once but still not continue to not be routed upon refresh?
2. How can I make the BehaviorSubject work until I receive a user object?

I have checked the following links:
[AuthGuard router angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313510/authguard-router-angular)
and [What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject). However, upon using a `Subject`, I may need to reauthenticate the user every time I visit a guarded route which is counterintuitive.

Comment: You don’t really get a second change in your canLoad.. the first emission is the only thing. Does it help when you start (in your pipe, before switchMap) with a filter that specifically checks for null?

Comment: Doesn't the if statement on the SwitchMap work the same way? But if I were to apply a filter operator before SwitchMap, what would I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've solved this problem. What I did was to create a new `Subject` at the AuthService. The guard checks if the `BehaviorSubject` inside the AuthService returns a null, and if it does, I will `switchMap` into using the `Subject`. Here is the code.

**AuthGuard**

```
canLoad() {
    return this.authServ.user.pipe(
        switchMap((user) => {
          if (!!user && !!user._token) {
            return of(user);
          }
          return this.authServ.initialLogin;
        }),
        map((user) => {
          if (!!user?._token) {
            return true;
          }
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        })
}
```

**AuthService**

```
user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null as any);
initialLogin = new Subject<User>();
reauthenticate(): Observable<User> {
    // return HTTP call here and pipe the user data into user BehaviorSubject
    return this.http.get<User>(URL, {withCredentials: true}).pipe(tap((user) => {
        this.initialLogin.next(user);
        this.user.next(user);
    }))
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authServ.reauthenticate().subscribe()
}
```

This way, I only authenticate once upon the start of the project